# Understanding Tracked Query

Tags: relayjs

I don't understand how *tracked queries* work.

Here there is a piece of my application:

*GRAPHQL*

```
type Admin implements Node {
  id: ID!
  program(slug: String!): Program
}

type Program implements Node {
  id: ID!
  slug: String!
  assessmentLink: String!
  subjectSubscription: Boolean!
}

input ProgramSetSubjectSubscriptionInput {
  programID: ID!
  subjectSubscription: Boolean!
  clientMutationId: String!
}

type ProgramSetSubjectSubscriptionPayload {
  program: Program
  clientMutationId: String!
}

type Mutations {
  programSetSubjectSubscription(input: ProgramSetSubjectSubscriptionInput!): ProgramSetSubjectSubscriptionPayload
}
```

*SERVER SIDE MUTATION*

```
import {
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLFloat,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInputObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLString
} from 'graphql';

import {
  fromGlobalId,
  mutationWithClientMutationId,
  cursorForObjectInConnection,
  offsetToCursor
} from 'graphql-relay';

import _ from 'lodash';

import db from '../../db';
import Program from '../types/Program';
import Admin, { ProgramEdge } from '../types/Admin';

export default mutationWithClientMutationId({

  name : 'ProgramSetSubjectSubscription',
  inputFields : {
    programID : {
      type : new GraphQLNonNull( GraphQLID )
    },
    subjectSubscription : {
      type : new GraphQLNonNull( GraphQLBoolean )
    }
  },

  async mutateAndGetPayload({ programID, subjectSubscription }) {

    const Program = db.model('Program');
    const localProgramId = fromGlobalId( programID ).id;

    const program = await Program.findById( localProgramId ).exec();
    program.subjectSubscription = subjectSubscription;

    await program.save();

    return { 
      localProgramId : program.id
    };
  },

  outputFields : {

    program : {
      type : Program,
      async resolve({ localProgramId }) {
        const Program = db.model('Program');
        return await Program.findById( localProgramId ).exec();
      }
    }

  }

});
```

*CLIENT SIDE MUTATION*

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class ProgramSetSubjectSubscription extends Relay.Mutation {

  static fragments = {
    program() {
      return Relay.QL`
        fragment on Program {
          id
        }
      `
    }
  };

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{programSetSubjectSubscription}`;
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on ProgramSetSubjectSubscriptionPayload {
        program {
          subjectSubscription
        }
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [
      {
        type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
        fieldsIDs : {
          program : this.props.program.id
        }
      }
    ];
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      programID : this.props.program.id,
      subjectSubscription : this.props.subjectSubscription
    };
  } 
}
```

Now I have a `Container` called `ProgramCard` with a `fragment` like this:

```
fragment on Program {
  name,
  assessmentLink,
  subjectSubscription,
  ${ProgramAutoInviteToggle.getFragment('program')}
  ${ProgramSubjectRegistrationLink.getFragment('program')}
}
```

The `Mutation` is called by `ProgramAutoInviteToggle` and should toggle the value of this `Program` `subjectSubscription` field. 
In the `ProgramCard` render method I want to show or not `ProgramSubjectRegistrationLink` depending on the `subjectSubscription` value.

The problem is that the actual mutation made by the client is the following:

```
query:
  mutation ProgramSetSubjectSubscription($input_0:ProgramSetSubjectSubscriptionInput!){programSetSubjectSubscription(input:$input_0){clientMutationId}}

variables:
  {
  "input_0": {
    "programID": "UHJvZ3JhbTo1NjM2OTY1MzFiZGM3MzI1MmFlYTk4MWE=",
    "subjectSubscription": false,
    "clientMutationId": "0"
  }
}
```

There is no trace of `subjectSubscription` field. Why??

Thank you very mutch for helping me with this. I really cannot figure it out!

Comment: Somone can help me on this?
I have a lot of other cases were I can't update my stores correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with the correct spelling of `fieldIDs`?

```js
getConfigs() {
  return [
    {
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {  // Instead of `fieldsIDs`
        program: this.props.program.id
      }
    }
  ];
}
```